# rename eclipse e4 application model file

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

When I renamed the file Application.e4xmi to something.e4xmi with the Refactor->rename feature then I could not start my e4 application anymore. I also made sure that in the plugin.xml file the product property is set to the same name:

```
     <property
       name="applicationXMI"
       value="something.e4xmi">
     </property>
```

and I had the same result.
Finally I removed that part completely and again no luck.

Error is:

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-05-07 20:18:15.738
!MESSAGE Unable to load resource platform:/plugin/com.example.e4.rcp.todo/Application.e4xmi
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Application.e4xmi
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Application.e4xmi
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.protocol.bundleentry.Handler.findBundleEntry(Handler.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleResourceHandler.openConnection(BundleResourceHandler.java:175)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLConnection.connect(PlatformURLConnection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLConnection.connect(PlatformURLConnection.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLConnection.getInputStream(PlatformURLConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.URIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(URIHandlerImpl.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
    ... 20 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-05-07 20:18:15.762
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
An error has occurred. See the log file
D:\_Project_AMT\replicate\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\todo.product\1399490294800.log.
```

Tried with Kepler Service Release 2 and with Kepler version 4.3.2 build M20140221-1700.

Any help/hint appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The `applicationXMI` property value normally includes the plugin id - `value="plugin id/Application.e4xmi"`

Comment: Added the above as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applicationXMI property value should include the plugin id:

```xml
<property
   name="applicationXMI"
   value="plugin-id/something.e4xmi">
</property>
```